# Any workaround for Java/Swing bug under Mac OS when opening new windows as tabs

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm developing a swing based Java application (Java 8) for Mac and Windows. Some users have set the mac system preference under "General" "Prefer Tabs when opening documents" to "Always" or "Full screen". When the setting is set to "Never" it works without problems.

[image]

This setting causes some weird state in which the window opens a new tab which results in a frozen application which can only be force quitted. I cannot assume that users know about this hidden setting in the Mac OS system preferences.

[image]

Three solutions would work for me:

- Find any workaround to prevent the window from opening other windows as tabs?
- Launching our bundled Java app with some -flag that disables this behaviour for the entire application
- Detecting if this mac system setting is enabled and then warn the user and quit the application (not really a good solution)

Comment: I realize that this is a silly, rhetorical question, nonetheless, are you certain that the problem is **not** in your [java] code? Does your _Swing_ application use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)? It's not clear to me from the screen capture in your question, but does your _Swing_ application contain a `JTabbedPane`?

Comment: Yes, this is not it. As soon as I change the mac setting to "Prefer Tabs when opening windows" to "Never" the window opens as a separate window (as intended).

Comment: Nonetheless, consider posting a [mcve] so that other people will be able to reproduce your problem which may help someone to find a solution for you.

Comment: I can confirm this is an issue https://community.jthink.net/t/jaikoz-and-big-sur/9791 that I am having as well since updating to BigSur, it is not a problem in the code, sorry I don't currenlty have a solution for you except the workaround of setting the Prefer tabs option to never

Comment: We now updated our bundled JDK to Java 15 and the problem is now solved in most cases. Sometimes though new JDialogs still open up as Tabs, but I could not find out what the reason is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change in Big Sur is causing a bug in Java https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8256465

There is a workaround from MacOS terminal window you can run

```
defaults write net.java.openjdk.cmd "AppleWindowTabbingMode" manual
```

or if you have java bundled within your own application use the value of CFBundleIdentifier in the applications **Info.plist** file

e.g

```
defaults write net.myapp.com "AppleWindowTabbingMode" manual
```

Comment: This workaround is the best for now, but the three options are "always", "fullscreen" or "manual" (not "never").

We are using a bundled JRE and so we had to exchange "net.java.openjdk.cmd" with our mac CFBundleIdentifier